# What can be said about the uniqueness of an ODE solved with separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

consider the following ODE which can be solved with separation of variables:

$$  x' = 2t (1+x^2), x(0) = 0 $$

The solution is:

$$  \lambda(t) = \tan(t^2) $$
But what can I say about the uniqueness of the solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The solution is unique, by the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is unique because $1+x^2\neq 0$ for any $x$. Hence the variables can be separated and the equation can be integrated.

In general, the uniqueness of the autonomous equations $\dot x=f(x)$ gets broken if for $\hat{x}$ such that $f(\hat{x})=0$ the improper integral 
$$
\int_{x_0}^\hat{x}\frac{dx}{f(x)}
$$
converges.