# Finding all the solutions to a certain partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'd like to prove that all the solutions to the free Schrödinger Equation are the functions $\Psi(x,t) = \int dk \Phi(k)\exp{i(kx-\omega t)}$ where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function.

The 1-Dimension free Schrödinger Equation is : $$i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\Psi$$

So to show the $\Leftarrow$ I started with the function $\exp{i(kx-\omega t)}$

I plugged it in the Wave Equation and found: $$\hbar \omega \Psi = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}\Psi$$

which is equivalent to $$\Psi = \Psi$$

provided $E = \hbar \omega = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m} = \frac{p^2}{2m} =  \frac{1}{2}mv^2$

Then by linearity, I can conclude since $$\int dk \Phi(k)\exp{i(kx-\omega t)}$$

is a "continuous linear combination" of $\exp{i(kx-\omega t)}$

That was for the $\Leftarrow$

For the $\Rightarrow$ I have this strange time and double spatial Differential Equation, and I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Maybe I should just plug in $A\exp{Bx} \exp{Ct}$ where $A,B,C$ are constants? But what proves me that there is not higher degree of $x$ or $t$ in the $\exp$ ?...

Comment: Solve using separation of variables.

Comment: Do you mean separate the variables and then integrate? Or is it the physics meaning factorizing as $f(x)g(t)$ ?

Comment: Write $\Psi(x,t)=f(x)g(t)$. If you find the solution, it is unique https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46285/what-can-be-said-about-the-uniqueness-of-an-ode-solved-with-separation-of-variab

Comment: Using separation of variables I find a solution that is in the form $f(x)\exp{(-i\omega t)} $where $f$ is an eigenvector of $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$

Comment: How can I conclude that $f(x) = \exp{ikx}$ ?...

Comment: Since $\Psi(x,t)$ satisfies the differential equation, it should be enough to show that for any initial condition $f(x)$, there exists $\Psi(x,t)$ with $\Psi(x,0) = f(x)$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog When you're talking about the initial condition $f(x)$ is it the same $f$ that is an eigenvector of $−\frac{ℏ^2}{2m}\frac{∂^2}{∂x^2}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using separation of variables $\Psi(x,t)=f(x)g(t)$, you can write
$$i\hbar\frac{dg}{dt}f=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}g\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$$
Divide by $\Psi$:
$$i\hbar\frac{dg}{dt}\frac1g=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac1f\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$$
Left hand side depends only on $t$, right hand side only on $x$. If they are equal, it means that both sides are equal to a constant that does not depend on $x$ or $t$. For reasons to be seen later, we call this constant $\hbar\omega$. Then the left hand side becomes $$i\hbar\frac1g\frac{dg}{dt}=\hbar\omega$$
Multiplying both sides with $dt$ and integrating, you get $$\ln g-ln A=-i\omega t$$ or $$g(t)=Ae^{-i\omega t}$$
Here $A$ is just an integration constant

The right hand side can now be written as
$$\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}+\hbar\omega f=0$$
The solution of this equation is the form $$f=Be^{ikx}$$
Plugging it in, you get $$\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}k^2=\hbar\omega$$
Once again $B$ is a constant that does not depend on $x$ or $t$, but can be a function of $\omega$ (or $k$). So your final solution is $$\psi_{k,\omega}(x,t)=C(k,\omega)e^{i(kx-\omega t)}\delta\left(\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}-\hbar\omega\right )$$

Comment: _The solution of this equation is..._ How do you consider the case where $\omega$ is negative? Do you manage this by making the $k$ imaginary?

Comment: Yes. Then the exponent is going to be real, so you will need to use the decaying part $e^{-|kx|}$

Comment: I am sorry for the late question. But what would be the initial condition in the case of the 
 free Schödinger Equation? ( Picard–Lindelöf requires an initial condition $y(t_0)=y_0$)